# Prove or disprove there are no integer solutions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm have no idea what to do with this.

Prove or disprove: There are no integer solutions to $3x^2 + 5y^2 = 13$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since $x^2$ and $y^2$ are both positive, you only have small number of cases to check.

Comment: Is it possible you meant "rational solutions"?

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do is treat the equation as only in one variable, for example $x$. If you proceed that way, then you'll have: $3x^2 + 5y^2 - 13 = 0$, where $a = 3, b = 0, c = 5y^2 - 13$. Then, by Bhaskara,
$$x = \frac{0 \pm \sqrt{0-4\cdot 3\cdot (5y^2 - 13)}}{6} = \frac{\sqrt{-60y^2+156}}{6} = \frac{2\sqrt{39-15y^2}}{3}$$
Now note that if $y \geq 2$, then $x \in \mathbb{C}$, so the only option for the square root not beeing complex is $y = 1$, but if $y = 1$, then you have $x = \frac{2\sqrt{24}}{3} = \frac{4\sqrt{6}}{3}$, that is not and integer solution and it's the only possible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The square of a integer will always be an integer, so both $x^2$ and $y^2$ are integers.

$y^2$ can equal $0,$ or $1$ but not $4$ or greater, as $5\times 4>13$.

When $y^2=0$, $3x^2=13$. As $13$ is not a multiple of $3$, this is impossible.

When $y^2=1$, $3x^2=13-5=7$. As $7$ is not a multiple of $3$, this is impossible.

As $y^2$ cannot have any values that satisfy the equation, it is therefore inpossible.